# The action can't be completed because the file is open in IIS Worker Process

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, c#-4.0, file-upload

I am uploading a image for a user & saving it on a specified location. The code is working fine in normal scenario i.e. user selects a image & save it, it works.

Challenge occurs when **user selects a image**( probably wrong image due to mistake) **& don't save it, but again selects a new image & then saves it.** 
This scenario gives me the error :

**"The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."**

When I try to delete image from the location at the time of error, file can't be deleted with message:

**"The action can't be completed because the file is open in IIS Worker Process
Close the file and try again."**

Code is like this:

```
            try
            {
                if (!Directory.Exists(folder))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(folder);

                msf = new MemoryStream();
                bytes=FileUpload1.FileBytes;
                msf.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(folder + "/" + filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite))
                {
                    //converting any graphic file type to jpeg format
                    Image img = Image.FromStream(msf);
                    img.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                    msf.WriteTo(stream);
                    IsuploadSuccess = true;
                    img.Dispose();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                IsuploadSuccess = false;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (msf != null)
                {
                    msf.Close();
                    msf.Dispose();
                }
            }
```

I have tried adding **"FileAccess.ReadWrite"** & **"FileShare.ReadWrite"** in file stream, but doesn't work either with all options in File stream.

Please help...

Comment: Can you please try to dispose that filestream also.

Comment: @Mahesh, Using{} block itself disposes the object after scope ends. But any way I tried that too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of getting solution of problem, I finally change approach to get rid to source of challenge. I change file name with UserID (unique) appended with CurrentDateTime converted to string & store it to temp folder until user save the change. This forms a different file each time for the challenge scenario. After save each file in temp folder created by the user (preceded by unique userid) is deleted & last changes are saved to respective directory.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and took me few hours to figure it out.
I my case the **Bitmap new(path)** had locked the file. I had to dispose of it before exiting the **using** block.
However it is the method by which I debugged it is important.
My approach in pinpointing the source of the problem was to open the folder where the image was saved and tracing the code line by line. After each line I deleted the file and did Ctrl+Z to put it back. If it gave an error when I tried to delete it, then that is the line that locked it. So I got to that line within 5 min.

```
using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new())
{
if (System.IO.File.Exists(path))
    {
        using(Bitmap bitmap = new(path))  <-- this solved it
        {
            ImageConverter imageConverter = new();
            bitmap.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
     }
 }
```